# QuickBlox save Dialogs in CoreData for offline viewing

Tags: ios, core-data, quickblox

Is there a way to save Quickblox dialogs and messages for viewing offline? I am trying to save messages, queue messages when there is no network to call the Quickblox service. Once the network is availabel the messages will be send?

I understand this can be achieved by using Core data, but I am not sure how. can anyone help me in achieving this? Any pointers to the solutions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save quickblox messages in any format & storage you want. It can be NSUserDefaults, CoreData, .txt file in Documents directory etc. 
QuickBlox SDK doesn't contain this function, but it is realized in iOS Chat Sample and Swift demo. Please have a look at the links below:

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios
http://quickblox.com/developers/Demo-swift-ios

Comment: Thank you will have a look. :-)